# Can I typealias a function with default parameters?

Tags: swift, swift4

Can I typealias a function whose parameters have defaults?
How?

In the following example, which does not work due to an error, I have:

- `executeCommands`, a function which executes a list of commands. This function can optionally receive another function as argument -- one which fetches the commands to be executed.
- `fetchCommandsFromDisk`, a default functions which fetches commands from disk.
- `Executioner.executeCommands()`, a the programs entry point.

  ```
  /* An attempt to typealias:Executioner\fetchCommandsFromDisk( (String)->[String] ) */
  typealias commandFetcherType = (String) -> [String]

  class Executioner {
      /* The function whose signature is to have a typealias. */
      func fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile file: String = "foobar") -> [String] {
          ...
      }

      /* A function which if called without arguments,
       * will fall back to a default argument which is
       * the above function. */
      static public func executeCommands(commandFetcher = fetchCommandsFromDisk) {
          /* This does not work, xcode reports:
             "ERROR: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" */
          let commands = commandFetcher()
          ... /* execute commands */ ...
      }
  }

  ...

  /*
   * Calling executeCommands without parameters.
   * This results in commands being fetched from disk, then executed.
   */
  Executioner.executeCommands()
  ```

Comment: this code is making my Xcode playground use 170% cpu

Comment: This is highly confusing (to me).  Someone much more knowledgable than me can give a theoretical answer, but.... I think you may have function and closure confused... is this "pseudo-code" ?

Comment: do you mean: "executeCommands(arg1: commandFetcherType = fetchCommandsFromDisk)" ??

Comment: @BooberBunz yes

Comment: Welp this is a real mind bender... me thinks I be out of my league.  I feel like Ahmad's answer surely is helpful?

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your code:

**1-** In order to use `fetchCommandsFromDisk` as a default for for static `executeCommands` method, you should also declare `fetchCommandsFromDisk` as *static* method, for instance:

```
static func fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile file: String = "foobar") -> [String] {
    print("\(#function): file value is: \(file)")
    return [""]
}
```

**2-** Declaring `executeCommands` signature as:

```
static public func executeCommands(commandFetcher = fetchCommandsFromDisk)
```

is *invalid*, you are missing the parameter name, so it should be instead:

```
static public func executeCommands(parameter: @escaping commandFetcherType = fetchCommandsFromDisk)
```

thus the whole method would be -for instance-:

```
static public func executeCommands(parameter: @escaping commandFetcherType = fetchCommandsFromDisk) {
    let commands = parameter

    commands("testing")
}
```

Note that calling `parameter` has to be done with parameters, for some reason it won't recognize `fetchCommandsFromDisk` default values for its parameter ("foobar"), instead it will look at `parameter` ("testing") value.

As a recap, the whole code would be:

```
typealias commandFetcherType = (String) -> [String]

class Executioner {
    static func fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile file: String = "foobar") -> [String] {
        print("\(#function): file value is: \(file)")
        return [""]
    }

    static public func executeCommands(parameter: @escaping commandFetcherType = fetchCommandsFromDisk) {
        let commands = parameter

        commands("testing")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Based on the above code, let's review the outputs for each method:

**---** Calling `fetchCommandsFromDisk` without passing a parameter:

```
Executioner.fetchCommandsFromDisk()
/* fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile:): file value is: foobar */
```

**---** Calling `fetchCommandsFromDisk` and passing a parameter:

```
Executioner.fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile: "hello!")
/* fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile:): file value is: hello! */
```

**---** Calling `executeCommands` without passing a function a parameter:

```
Executioner.executeCommands()
/* fetchCommandsFromDisk(fromFile:): file value is: testing */
```

remember that you will get "testing" based on what has been passed in the implementation of `executeCommands`, but *not* the default value of `fetchCommandsFromDisk`.

**---** Calling `executeCommands` and passing a -function- parameter:

```
func customHandle(file: String) -> [String] {
    print(#function)
    return ["Hello", "World!"]
}

Executioner.executeCommands(parameter: customHandle)
/* customHandle(file:) */
```

Comment: I just updated the code in the question with new names as to make it more easy to understand. I also fixed 1. Do you mind if I modify your answer to reflect my changes?

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson Done :)